# Formulation of probit and mixture models

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the probit model

$
y_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \textrm{if $z_i=x_i^{'}\beta+\varepsilon_i>0$}\\
0 & \textrm{if $z_i=x_i^{'}\beta+\varepsilon_i \leq 0$}
\end{array} \right.
$

with $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$ where the likelihood function is:

$p(y|\beta)=\prod_{i=1}^{N} Pr[Y_i=1|\beta]^{y_i} (1-Pr[Y_i=1|\beta])^{1-y_i}$

and mixture model:

$
y_t = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
N(\mu_0, \sigma^2_0) & \textrm{if $s_t=0$}\\
N(\mu_1, \sigma^2_1) & \textrm{if $s_t=1$}
\end{array} \right.
$

where the likelihood function is:

$p(y|\theta)=\prod_{t=1}^{T} (1-\lambda) \phi(y_t|\mu_0, \sigma^2_0)+\lambda \phi(y_t|\mu_1, \sigma^2_1).$

My question is regarding the formulation of the likelihood functions. Why for the probit model we multiply $Pr[Y_i=1|\beta]^{y_i}$ with $1-Pr[Y_i=1|\beta]^{y_i}$ and use indicators $y_i$ and $1-y_i$ in the exponentiation? For the mixture model case I guess that we just have a mixture of the probability distributions such that we add the densities and use indicators $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$. I am aware that the formulation of probit model and mixture model are different, however I am looking for the mathematical or theoretical guidelines that back up these formulations.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the probit function: note that in case $y_i = 0$ the likelihood of this single observation should equal $\mathbb{P}(y_i = 0 | \beta)$ and in case $y_i = 1$ the likelihood of this single observation should equal $\mathbb{P}(y_i = 1 | \beta)$. This is exactly what we get by using the described likelihood function:
\begin{align*}
y_i = 0 &\implies \mathbb{P}(y_i = 1|\beta)^{y_i}\mathbb{P}(y_i = 0| \beta)^{1-y_i} = 
\mathbb{P}(y_i = 0|\beta) \\
y_i = 1 &\implies \mathbb{P}(y_i = 1|\beta)^{y_i}\mathbb{P}(y_i = 0| \beta)^{1-y_i} = 
\mathbb{P}(y_i = 1|\beta)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am aware that choosing either 0 or 1 leads to the corresponding model. My question is why do we put either $y_i$ or $1-y_i$ in the exponentiation? Is there a strict rule that we need to do so?